# Need the more recent between two DATETIME's in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

I have two SQL DATETIME's that I need to compare. I need to set the value of a column to be the more recent date between the two. Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was

```
CASE
    WHEN COALESCE(@Date1, '1/1/1980') > COALESCE(@Date2, '1/1/1980')
    THEN @Date1...
    ELSE @Date2...
    END
```

I ended up doing this because if one of the dates was null, then the compare wouldn't work correctly. So I used COALESCE with a date in the past that I knew would be a good baseline, then did my comparison. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Use a CASE statement.

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn = CASE WHEN @Date1 > @Date2 THEN @Date1 ELSE @Date2 END
    WHERE...
```

Answer (score 1):

`GREATEST` would work for both numbers and dates.

```
update table set date_column = greatest(date1, date2);
```

`greatest(date1, date2)` will return `date2` if `date2` is **later** than `date1` and vice versa.

Comment: That would depend on the RDBMS. SQL Server, for example, does not have a GREATEST function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATEDIFF` function to compare the dates.

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME = '1/1/2010'
DECLARE @Date2 DATETIME = '2/1/2010'

SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, @Date1, @Date2) < 0 THEN @Date1 ELSE @Date2 END
```

and UPDATE

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyDate = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, @Date1, @Date2) < 0 THEN Date1 ELSE Date2 END
WHERE <insert your conditions>
```

Assuming SQL Server.

Comment: 'DATETIME' includes time, if there is any on the OPs data, then this will not work, and will produce incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to set the value of a column to
>   be the more recent date between the
>   two.

I'd use the less than operator.

Yes, that's correct: the less than operator. No, not the greater than operator.

The reason is I find temporal data easier to read as a 'timeline' i.e. date values ascending in left-to-right order. Hence:

```
UPDATE YourTable
   SET your_col = CASE 
                      WHEN @Date1 < @Date2 THEN @Date2 
                      ELSE @Date1 
                   END
 WHERE ...
```